# Regular expression in c++ for searching string pattern

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a string like this:

```
string s ="one 1 two 2 three 3";
```

I want to write a regular expression such that when the user inputs "one" i should print 1, if the input given as "two"...any suggestions or help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these key values pairs in a string separated by spaces? Why do you want to use regex?

Comment: Have you tried something specific? Or are you hoping someone codes it up fo you? What are you stuck on? Regex? User input?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code or regex writing service. We're more than happy to help, but you're expected to make an effort to figure things out yourself. You should spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages, in particular [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Ditch the reg-ex. Write some code instead. Use something of the form

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> m = {{"one", 1}, {"two", 2}, {"three", 3}};
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input
    std::cout << m[input];
}
```

Note the fancy initialisation: valid from C++11 onwards.

Answer (score 4):

very easy:

```
std::string s = "one 1 two 2 three 3";

std::regex rx( "([a-z]+) (\\d+)" );
std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > mr;

std::regex_search( s, mr, rx );
std::cout << mr.str( 1 ) << '\n';  // one
std::cout << mr.str( 2 ) << '\n';  // 1
```

and for the whole match:

```
std::string temp = s;
while( std::regex_search( temp, mr, rx ) ){
    std::cout << mr.str( 1 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << mr.str( 2 ) << '\n';
    temp = mr.suffix().str();
}
```

the output:

```
one
1
two
2
three
3
```

and eventually:

```
std::string ui; //user_input

std::string temp = s;
while( std::regex_search( temp, mr, rx ) ){

    std::getline( std::cin, ui );

    if( ui == mr.str( 1 ) ){
       std::cout << mr.str( 2 ) << '\n';
    }

    temp = mr.suffix().str();
}
```

NOTE: this is not a perfect solution since `regex_search` match the items one by one. So you should enter `one` then `two` then `three`

**test**

```
 ideas $  ./temp 
one
1
two
2
three
3
 ideas $
```

---

May as you want, but I put it just for learning to see how it works:

```
std::string s = "one 1 two 2 three 3";

std::string ui; //user_input
std::getline( std::cin, ui );

std::string pt = "(" + ui + ")" + " ";
std::regex rx( pt + "(\\d)" );
std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > mr;

std::regex_search( s, mr, rx );
if( ui == mr.str( 1 ) ){
   std::cout << mr.str( 2 ) << '\n';
}
```

**test**

```
 ideas $  ./temp
one
1
 ideas $  ./temp
two
2
 ideas $  ./temp
three
3
 ideas $
```

Comment: Thank you so much k-five. Appreciate your patience in giving detailed explanation.

Comment: @vishwa Not a problem, please accept the answer if it satisfies you. thank you.